# 'ExpectedConditions' does not exist on type 'typeof protractor'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, protractor

I'm writing a protractor test in TypeScript in Visual Studio 2013 and I'm getting the error:

> Property 'ExpectedConditions' does not exist on type 'typeof protractor'.

I read a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032168/typescript-compile-error-property-bodyparser-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-e)) but it did not help my situation.

This is my page objects code:

```
class SheetObjects {
    EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    showList = element(by.buttonText('Show as List'));
    copyItem = element.all(by.binding('item.name')).get(2);
    copyDiv = element(by.className('md-inline-list-icon-label'));
    alertItem = element(by.binding('alert'));
    alertDiv = element(by.css('[ng-if="alert"]'))

    NavigateToPage() {
        browser.get('https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.bottomSheet');
    }

    WaitForElements(element: any) {
        browser.wait(() => element.isPresent(), 5000);
    }

    ClickOn(element: any) {
        element.click();
    }
}
module.exports = new SheetObjects();
```

This is my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="angular-protractor.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jasmine.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="1.3.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="node.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="1.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Protractor" version="0.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="2.45.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="selenium-webdriver.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.3.7" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I figured ExpectedConditions would be included in one of those packages but so far nothing has fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I figured ExpectedConditions would be included in one of those packages but so far nothing has fixed it.

its not https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ExpectedConditions This implies that the definition is a bit *out of date* with the current *actual* protractor code : http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions

## Hot fix

Just use it in an untyped manner:

```
EC = (<any>protractor).ExpectedConditions;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I went on vacation shortly after asking that question.  And it worked beautifully thank you.