# ExpectedConditions is undefined in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am a newbie in protractor and using protractor `Version 4.0.2`

But when I have below code I get error against `protractor` keyword

```
   import { browser } from 'protractor/globals';

   let EC =  protractor.ExpectedConditions;
```

Error:

```
[ts] 
Cannot find name 'protractor'.
```

Do I need to import anything specifically here?

Further I tried ['ExpectedConditions' does not exist on type 'typeof protractor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172265/expectedconditions-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-protractor?rq=1). No luck though.

Comment: You haven't imported protractor. I don't use `protractor`, but you might want to try: `import { browser, protractor } from 'protractor/globals';`

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, perfect. Can you please add this as a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For version 4.0.2 - 4.0.8, ExpectedConditions has been exported via:

```
import { ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor/globals';
```

It could also be accessed from the global protractor object:

```
import { protractor } from 'protractor/globals';

let EC = protractor.EC;
```

In version 4.0.9+, the import is slightly different. The import is no longer `'protractor/globals'` and should just be from `'protractor'`. For example:

```
import { protractor } from 'protractor';
```

4.0.14 update:

With pull request https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3766, EC is no longer static and is tied to the browser instance. So if your browser session is closed, you will need to set up EC again. If you do not, you will get a selenium error about the session being closed.

```
describe('ec' () => {
  it('is tied to the browser instance', () => {
    let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    // Or EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
  });
});
```